# Script tags with type 'text/x-handlebars' disappear from the page when tested by Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, capybara, handlebars.js, phantomjs

Project setup:
Server: Rails & Haml
Testing: Capybara - Cucumber - Poltergeist - PhantomJS
Client side: Ember.js

There is a page that uses only one component of Ember (without loading full-stack of route-controller-model) and for some reason, script tag with the template for this component is not rendered on the page, in tests only.
Component works well on page if tested manually, no errors or warnings displayed. If type is differ from 'text/x-handlebars' it will be rendered. There is no such problem for other Ember pages.

Sample markup:

_form.html.haml

```
=render 'ember/templates/components/foo_bar'
.row  
  .span12
    <form markup>
```

ember/templates/components/foo_bar.html.haml

```
%script{type: 'text/x-handlebars', data:{'template-name' => 'components/foo-bar'}}  
  .input-append  
    <template markup>
```

How can I render this template on page?

Answer (score 1):

Just a workaround rather than a solution, but worked for me:

Haml replaced with handelbars (.hbs) template
Template moved to 'templates' folder
'templates' folder added to application.js manifest
Ember-rails do the rest - compile & include handlebars code into page

Answer (score 0):

Just add 'js: true'

```
it 'tests the script on presence', js: true do
  . . .
end
```

Comment: Thanks, but i already use @javascript tag before tests. Other js works fine.